# How to produce a data stream of Tuples from two data streams where one is keyed and the other isn't?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I've got two streams that I want to "join":

- Stream A is a keyed stream of events which are keyed by an account id. It's keyed because I want to ensure that these events are processed in order later on.
- Stream B is a stream of IDs which are strings. These IDs cannot be re-used.

I want to assign an ID from Stream B to an event in Stream A before feeding that into my process function which will use the ID and Event to produce a new object. IDs from Stream B can't be re-used later.

I'm concerned that keying Stream A before producing stream AB and re-keying it once more would be rather costly. Is there a simple way to produce what I want without incurring the cost of keying twice?

I've tried connecting both streams and using a RichCoFlatMapFunction implementation to produce a Tuple2 of what I wanted, but it didn't work since my ID stream is not keyed. The alternative appears to be through the use of a broadcast function, but I want to guarantee that the IDs are only ever used once rather than being exposed to all parallel operators.

Comment: IIUC you want to use Stream B to provide unique IDs for each element of Stream A. If so, how do you know that you're generating these IDs at exactly the right rate to be added to Stream A? Flink works via a "push" model, so you can only control the data rate for a stream via a custom Source.